# Don't I lose functionality by coding to an Interface? List vs ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist, interface

(1) `List<?> myList = new ArrayList<?>();`

(2) `ArrayList<?> myList = new ArrayList<?>();`

I understand that with (1), implementations of the List interface can be swapped. It seems that (1) is typically used in an application regardless of need (myself I always use this).

I am wondering with (1) I don't have specific ArrayList functionality right? I only have the general List functions. So I don't have access to anything array list specific? And if so? How can I get access to ArrayList specific functionality? Do I swap the List with an ArrayList or can I cast the List to an ArrayList?

Comment: "*So I dont have access to anything array list specific?*" - Right.

Comment: It's a tradeoff.  You can't call ArrayList-specific methods; you have the freedom to switch the implementation to some other type of List just by changing the declaration.  (This goes double when talking about the return type of a method).  So a good rule of thumb is to use the least-specific variable type that matches what you need to do with it.

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: "loose" is a different word to "lose"

Comment: "can I cast the List to an ArrayList?"—If you *need* your list to be an ArrayList, then you're not programming to the List interface and you should just store your reference as an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typically expose the interface to the public and keep the specific implementation to yourself. This is to make swapping it out with something different easier, as consumers only know that it is a list. If you only use the reference within your own object, then there's no need to hide the specific implementation. If you need an array list then for all means do store the reference as an arraylist!